# how to add background image to css3 arrow

Tags: html, css

For a project I have to include a background image into a css3 arrow shape (facing right). Below is the HTML/CSS. What I want to achieve is that the image extends from the rectangled box over in the triangular (border) box.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="arrow"></div>
```

Css:

```
#arrow {
    width: 128px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/Bee-apis.jpg);
}
#arrow:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 128px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #f0f0f0;
}
#arrow:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 129px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 12px solid #999;
}
```

[**Here's the fiddle I'm working with**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malachute/V4A9T/1/). How do you approach this problem? I have no problems using code that is not compatible with IE7/8/9.

Comment: I didn't get you.. can you please explain clearly? I think nobody understood your explanation that is why no comment/answer for so long time.

Comment: Do you mean like this? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V4A9T/8/).

Comment: I can see a css solution for this using `transform` properties but I don't see the point of using image and css arrow. The point of using css arrows is that you don't need images. So why don't you just use an image for your arrow and forget about css?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've added an image to explain the problem. Is there a way to fill the border box with a background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do something in a harder way, but here's your [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/8PfY5/)

You can use svg to draw a path.

```
<svg id="svg-defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-triangle">
            <polygon points="0,0 150,0 300,150 150,300 0,300 0,0"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely look into this method for a future build. For now I went with a full background image.

Comment: @ANGRYKOREAMAN If you look at my demo it does use a full background image, the svg only draws a path as a mask to crop the arrow shape for you. This is more efficient and scalable.

Answer (score -1):

I think he need to add background to this arrow, do you ?
If you want to do this, I guess you can't. You can resolve this through css3 transform rotate, skew etc.
Of course if you don't want use static img for this.